# How to get id value from Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to mvc please help me how can i get id value from the table.Here im using `IModelBinder`

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>EmpId</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach(Employee emp in Model.GetEmployee)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@emp.Emp_Id</td>
            <td>@emp.Email</td>

            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "GetById", "EmployeeManagement", new {id=emp.Emp_Id})</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When i Bind as  `new {id=emp.Emp_Id}` Im getting Length as 18 for every column Like `http://localhost:9426/EmployeeManagement/GetById?Length=18`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Action Link with this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "GetById", "EmployeeManagement", new { id = emp.Emp_Id }, new { })
```

Comment: oo Greate Mr Jilani Bhai Its Working Fine Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `Html.ActionLink` overload with 4 parameters, which the last one is an Object. This parameter refers to **route parameters** (see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936(v=vs.118).aspx).

If you want to refer to the **HTML parameters** you need the overload with 5 parameters (two last are Objects), where 4th parameter still the route parameters (which you can leave as *blank object* `{}`) and the 5th is the HTML parameters (which are specified as query parameters) (see more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx).

So, you could try to substitute your `@Html.ActionLink` expression like this (notice the blank object addition on the 4th parameter):

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "GetById", "EmployeeManagement", new {}, new {id=emp.Emp_Id})</td>
```

Comment: Im Getting Error as Invalied Expression as ( {

Comment: Sorry, maybe it can be that I missed the `new` keyword before the blank Object, I edit the answer with the fix.

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetById(Int32)' in 'Mvc_Angular.Controllers.EmployeeManagementController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Its Working wen i changed as              <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "GetById",new { id = emp.Emp_Id })</td>